# Problem with display of presentation

Tags: beamer

I am trying to create a presentation in latex and have the following

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{Anthony Robinson}
\title{Irrational and Transcendental Numbers}
\subtitle{Mathematics Project}
%\logo{}
\institute{University of Lincoln School of Maths and Physics}
\date{April 30, 2019}
%\subject{}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \begin{frame}{Summary}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item A rational number is a number which can be expressed in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. If a number cannot be expressed in this form it is said to be irrational, e.g. $\sqrt{2}$ or $\pi$.
            \item An algebraic number is a number that can be expressed as the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients, i.e. if a number $z$ is the root of $$a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 +\dots+a_nx^n=0 \quad \text{where}\quad a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\forall i$$ the $z$ is said to be algebraic of degree $n$. If a number is not algebraic then it is said to be transcendental. 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Important note}
        It is possible for a number to be irrational but not transcendental, e.g. $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational (this is proved later) but is algebraic as it is the root of the polynomial $x^2-2=0$.
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Important Results}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that in the output of the slide, in the banner at the bottom, it displays a bracket, (, and then "University of Lincoln".

How do I get rid of the bracket, or get rid of the "University of Lincoln" bit.

This is the first time I have tried to create a presentation in latex so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank-you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked,

> How do I get rid of ... the "University of Lincoln" bit [in the banner line]?

You need to change

```
\institute{University of Lincoln School of Maths and Physics}
```

to

```
\institute[]{University of Lincoln School of Maths and Physics}
```

By default, the "short" version of the institute-related information is equal to the material in curly braces, i.e., the main argument of `\institute`. The optional short version is what's placed in square brackets. By placing *nothing* inside the square brackets, nothing gets passed to the banner line shown at the bottom of the page.

[image]

The following screenshot shows the banner line once the document is recompiled:

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank-you very much, I have accepted your comment as the answer

Comment: @user182595 - You're most welcome. By the way, the "optional short version" is also available for the `\title`, `\author`, and `\date` directives. E.g., if you wanted to display "A. Robinson" rather than "Anthony Robinson" in the banner line, you'd write `\author[A. Robinson]{Anthony Robinson}`.

Comment: Thank-you very much, its nice to have someone properly explain everything instead of just changing code and leaving it there. Very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

The `Madrid`  theme uses the `infolines` outer theme in which the contents of the footline are defined. In the original definition (copied from `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty` you can find the following line:

> `\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
>       \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}`

that inserts the author name and the institute's name into the leftmost colored box in the footline.

In order to remove the institute's name you can redefine the footline as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{Anthony Robinson}
\title{Irrational and Transcendental Numbers}
\subtitle{Mathematics Project}
%\logo{}
\institute{University of Lincoln School of Maths and Physics}
\date{April 30, 2019}
%\subject{}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
 \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \maketitle


\end{document}
```

[image]